# How to move over to the right cell in Excel after hitting enter without changing the "Options" settings

Tags: excel, move, enter

I'm trying to figure out how to move into the right cell after hitting enter without having to change it in the Options settings.  Or if not, how to have each worksheet within a workbook go a different direction when I hit Enter.  (i.e. Sheet 1: when you hit Enter, it goes to the right cell, Sheet 2: when you hit Enter it goes down).

Answer (score 3):

You could use VBA to change the Enter key's behavior when a sheet is activated (when you click a tab).

To do this go to your VBE (Ctrl+F11) and find your Workbook's code:

[image]

And double click "ThisWorkbook" to add code to the Workbook object.

In there you can use something like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Or Sh.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
    ElseIf Sh.Name = "Sheet2" Or Sh.Name = "sheet4" Then
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
    End If
End Sub
```

This will run anytime a sheet/tab is activated. It will flip the Enter key's behavior similar to you manually going into options and changing it yourself.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that if you are unsure on how to VBA an [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) property, you can usually record yourself changing the option. Examining the recorded code will show the correct syntax. See [Excel Application members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198091.aspx) for a full list.

Comment: @JNevill This is what I put in the code, but it isn't moving right.                                Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet3" Then
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
    ElseIf Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Or Sh.Name = "sheet2" Or Sh.Name = "sheet4" Or Sh.Name = "sheet5" Or Sh.Name = "sheet6" Or Sh.Name = "sheet7" Then
        Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlDown
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 2):

Press TAB to move to the right

Comment: You can also start in the first cell with [ctrl]+shift]+[→] then type and hit [enter↵].